# DT::datatable clearing default filters

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I would like to put default filters on a `DT::datatable` in a shiny application.  I'm able to get the default filters in place, but removing the filters is not behaving as I would expect.

### Example 1

An example of a datatable with no filters:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      DT::dataTableOutput("mtcars")
    ),

  server =
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
      output$mtcars <- 
        DT::renderDataTable({
          mtcars$gear <- factor(as.character(mtcars$gear))
          datatable(
            data = mtcars,
            filter = "top",
            options = 
              list(
                pageLength = 50
              )
          )
        })
    })
)
```

Notice that in this example, when you manually select "3" under the `gear` column, a little gray box appears that let's you know "3" is selected.

[image]

Then, when you are out of the filter selection, there is a little x in a circle that lets you clear the filter.

[image]

### Example 2

In this example, I've preloaded "3" into the filter when the datatable loads.

```
shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      DT::dataTableOutput("mtcars")
    ),

  server =
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
      output$mtcars <- 
        DT::renderDataTable({
          mtcars$gear <- factor(as.character(mtcars$gear))
          datatable(
            data = mtcars,
            filter = "top",
            options = 
              list(
                pageLength = 50,
                searchCols = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                                  NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                                  NULL, NULL, list(search = '["3"]'), NULL)
              )
          )
        })
    })
)
```

Notice that the filter box doesn't have the x in a circle to clear out the filter.  If I click in the box and click out without making changes, the circle will appear, but will take no action when clicked.  The only way to clear the filter is to select a value and then clear out the values as I would if I hadn't preloaded the filters.

[image]

Anyone else had this problem before?

EDIT: Hopefully this really cheesy imagery helps clarify the discrepancy between the two.  I'm using DT version 0.1.57 (most recent on GitHub)

[image]

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Both examples are working fine for me. What is your DT version?

Comment: @Berecht, I'm using version 0.1.57 (most recent on GitHub), and have observed the same behavior in 0.1.16 (I upgraded this morning to see if the problem would resolve).  I also added another image with a (sort of) side by side comparison.

Comment: Seems that there is a bug between DT and shiny. When only using DT the problems do not appear, so i would suggest to create a issue on the shiny Github.

Comment: Have you tried pre-loading the options with, say, 3 _and_ null? Maybe the reason the x doesn't do anything is that there isn't a filter to reset to?

Comment: @EmileZäkiev I don't believe I did. If memory serves, I ended up putting in a button to redraw the table entirely if the filters needed to be cleared. Wasn't great, but got me through

Comment: @Benjamin cool thanks, sorry for asking without checking first. I think they actually fixed it now as of 2024!!